# Is this a PEX line with a compression fitting leaking?

Tags: plumbing, pex, copper

This section of pipe is the incoming main to the house. I *believe* it's PEX but need confirmation. It transitions here to copper throughout the rest of the house. Anyway I replaced inline the PRV right above this section today and this pipe section swiveled/rotated a bit back and forth in place on that 90 degree elbow pex fitting. BTW if I'm stating anything incorrectly please let me know.

Anyway I have a very, very small drip it appears where I'm pointing. That appears to be a really old compression fitting on the pex? coming in from the wall.

1st off am I correct in my assessment of the parts and if I disassemble this can I remove the compression fitting and install a new one? I *believe* the one on there is aging and when I rotated the pipe just a tad during the PRV install it loosened it just enough to be a small problem.

I'd need to know what tool to use to remove the old fitting, and reinstall compressed. I really don't want to pay the highway robbery prices around here for repair, and would do same-same to what's pictured. I also have the key to turn the water off at the street before repair. Thanks!

EDIT: I found the specific compression part; appears to be a SharkBite PEX clamp: https://www.lowes.com/pd/SharkBite-10-Pack-1-2-in-dia-Stainless-Steel-PEX-Pinch-Clamp-Crimp-Fitting/1000182819

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

SOLUTION: Adding as it might help someone. The answer led me in the right direction. At 1st I cut away the vertical PEX, cut a new piece, got a new male 3/4" adapter to replace the worn one on top, and added new copper crimp rings. It looked awesome, but leaked. There was a lurking problem. The original elbow at the bottom after removing the vertical PEX piece revealed it had been badly scored by a knife by a previous 'plumber.' This setup was waiting to leak. The problem with the copper rings is you have to cut off a generous piece of PEX and use a special cutting tool. The PEX crimp stainless clamps are easier to remove in place. Since I had to cut away PEX coming from the wall to remove the damaged elbow, I had no forgiveness in my next setup. I had Sharkbite connectors as plan B, but still wanted to use crimp clamps. I bought the other PEX crimp tool from Lowe's and the stainless steel clamps. This way if I clamped the new elbow and for whatever reason there was a leak, I could cut away the clamp in place, remove the elbow and go with plan B to use Sharkbite (would not be able to do this with a copper ring). However my plan A worked and the new elbow and crimp clamps worked like a charm. I also have both tools and sets of clamps for the future for less than paying for a repair person. No leaks and working great!

[image: End working solution]

Comment: Your repair looks great! Nice job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipe coming out of the wall looks like PEX with a standard crimp ring. The other rings look to be 'pinch' or 'clinch' rings.

The drip may stop if you re-crimp the ring with a set of PEX crimpers. Unfortunately, crimp rings are not intended to be removed and are typically just cut off with the fitting and replaced. You may be able to surgically cut the ring with a hacksaw blade (just holding the blade in your hand) without cutting the plastic PEX and peel off the ring and replace it.

If you don't have the tool to crimp a new ring or pinch a crimp ring, it might be best to remove the existing 90° and the male adaptor and replace it with a SharkBite 90° and SharkBite male adaptor. These fittings can be installed on PEX (or copper) without needing a specialized tool.

Comment: Think you can rent the crimper, but for one or two fittings shark bite type fitting might be cheaper(saves the trip to return anyway).

Comment: So I took your advice with my Ace Hardware 20% off coupon and got the Sharkbite copper ring crimping tool. I recrimped that copper ring and it's solid. I'm watching and I think it's good. What I'm realizing though is I think it's the lower PEX clamp on that vertical piece that's slowly leaking and it was obviously running to the bottom. I don't think that style can be re-crimped to make a difference correct? It's a different crimp tool which I don't mind buying (cheaper than paying someone) but that type can only be replaced correct?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't re-cinch it - probably as likely to work as re-crimping an existing crimp.

Comment: You can re-cinch it, yes. However you'll need yet another tool to do that. Basically there are a couple of different kinds of cinch tools you can use, with the main difference being the level of force needed to cinch correctly.

Comment: I assume you are turning the water off and venting the pressure on the water line before performing this repair.